# Show count of unique values in datasummary and combine two different tables of descriptive statistics using data

Tags: r, modelsummary

I really like the `modelsummary` package and i'm trying to produce a single table that mixes descriptive statistics of different types. The first part is easy: I can make basic descriptives of `var2` and `var3` before. I can't get the second part right, though.

1. I'd like to get a count of the unique entries of the variable `var1`, i.e. 26.
2. I'd like to be able to combine the two into one table.

```
var1<-rep(LETTERS, 5)
var2<-rnorm(length(var1), mean=50, sd=10)
var3<-rnorm(length(var1), mean=10, sd=5)
df<-data.frame(var1, var2, var3)
library(gr)
library(modelsummary)

#This gets the descriptives of var2 and var3
datasummary(var2+var3~Mean+SD+N, data=df)
#htis returns a long column of the number of entries of each value of var1; I would just like the number 26 here and combine it with the above
datasummary(var1~length, data=df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on `add_row` (https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/articles/datasummary.html#add_rows)

```
new_row <- data.frame('var1',
                       "-",
                       "-",
                       length(unique((var1))))

datasummary(var2+var3~Mean+SD+N, data=df, 
            add_rows = new_row)
```

Answer (score 2):

Mixing factor and numeric variables in `datasummary()` is kind of tricky. Here are two options.

The first approach is to create a first table with `output="data.frame"`, and to feed it to the `add_rows` argument of a second table, inserting “empty” columns as necessary to align the two tables:

```r
library(modelsummary)

var1<-rep(LETTERS[1:5], 5)
var2<-rep(LETTERS[8:12], 5)
var3<-rnorm(length(var1), mean=50, sd=10)
var4<-rnorm(length(var1), mean=10, sd=5)
df<-data.frame(var1, var2, var3, var4)

# function to insert empty columns
empty <- function(...) ""

ar <- datasummary(var1 + var2 ~ empty + empty + N,
                  data = df,
                  output = "data.frame")

datasummary(var3 + var4 ~ Heading("") * empty + Mean + SD + N,
            data = df,
            add_rows = ar)
```

|  |  | Mean | SD | N |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| var3 |  | 52.66 | 9.35 | 25 |
| var4 |  | 9.21 | 5.25 | 25 |
| var1 | A |  |  | 5 |
|  | B |  |  | 5 |
|  | C |  |  | 5 |
|  | D |  |  | 5 |
|  | E |  |  | 5 |
| var2 | H |  |  | 5 |
|  | I |  |  | 5 |
|  | J |  |  | 5 |
|  | K |  |  | 5 |
|  | L |  |  | 5 |

The second approach is to use the `datasummary_balance` template function with `~1` as a formula argument. This is of course less flexible, but it works for simple cases:

```r
datasummary_balance(~ 1, data = df)
```

|  |  | Mean | Std. Dev. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| var3 |  | 52.7 | 9.4 |
| var4 |  | 9.2 | 5.2 |
|  |  | N | Pct. |
| var1 | A | 5 | 20.0 |
|  | B | 5 | 20.0 |
|  | C | 5 | 20.0 |
|  | D | 5 | 20.0 |
|  | E | 5 | 20.0 |
| var2 | H | 5 | 20.0 |
|  | I | 5 | 20.0 |
|  | J | 5 | 20.0 |
|  | K | 5 | 20.0 |
|  | L | 5 | 20.0 |