# R datasummary: Show N and percent in one column

Tags: r, modelsummary

I am currently trying to display the count of factor levels (e.g., gender) and their relative frequency per group (e.g., treatment group) using datasummary. In addition, I would like to combine this with the display of quantitative variables (e.g., age) with their respective mean and standard deviation.

So far, I created a function to display mean and sd in one column and managed to calculate N and percentages. However, I am struggling with creating a function that displays N and percentage in one column as well as adding the empty column to the  datasummary of the quantitative variable to combine both frames (based on [Show count of unique values in datasummary and combine two different tables of descriptive statistics using data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71737847/show-count-of-unique-values-in-datasummary-and-combine-two-different-tables-of-d)).

```
library(modelsummary)
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(123)
iris$gender <- factor(sample(1:3, size = 150, replace = T), 
                      labels = c("Male", "Female", "Other"))
iris$job <-  factor(sample(1:5, size = 150, replace = T), 
                    labels = c("Student", "Worker", "CEO", "Other", "None"))
empty <- function(...) ""

MeanSD = function(x) {
  M = mean(x, na.rm = T)
  SD = sd(x, na.rm = T)
  MSD = paste(round(M, 2), " (",round(SD,2), ")", sep = "")
  return(MSD)
}
#This function does not work properly
  NP = function(x, y) {
    N = N(x)
    P = Percent(x, y, denom = "col")
    out = paste(N, " (",P, ")", sep = "")
    return(NP)
  }
iris_tab1 <- iris %>% dplyr::select(Species,
                                    Gender = gender,
                                    Job = job,
                                    Length = Sepal.Length)
tbl_1 <- datasummary((Heading("")*N + Heading("")*Percent(fn = function(x, y) 100 * length(x) / length(y), denom = "col"))*(Gender + Job)~Species,
                          data = iris_tab1,
                          fmt = 2,
                          output = 'data.frame'
)
tbl_1

#Cannot add the empty column
tbl_2 <- datasummary(Heading("")*(MeanSD)*Length~empty+Species, 
                          data = iris_tab1,
                          output = 'data.frame'
)
tbl_2
```

Comment: What package is `datasummary` from?

Comment: Its from modelsummary: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/modelsummary/modelsummary.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`empty` is a function. `MeanSD` is a function. All functions need to go on the same side of the `datasummary` formula:

```r
library(modelsummary)
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(123)
iris$gender <- factor(sample(1:3, size = 150, replace = T),
    labels = c("Male", "Female", "Other"))
iris$job <- factor(sample(1:5, size = 150, replace = T),
    labels = c("Student", "Worker", "CEO", "Other", "None"))

empty <- function(...) ""

MeanSD = function(x) {
    M = mean(x, na.rm = T)
    SD = sd(x, na.rm = T)
    MSD = paste(round(M, 2), " (", round(SD, 2), ")", sep = "")
    return(MSD)
}

iris_tab1 <- iris %>%
    dplyr::select(Species,
        Gender = gender,
        Job = job,
        Length = Sepal.Length)

tbl_2 <- datasummary(Heading("") * Length ~ empty + MeanSD * Species,
    data = iris_tab1,
    output = "data.frame")
tbl_2
#>     empty      setosa  versicolor   virginica
#> 1         5.01 (0.35) 5.94 (0.52) 6.59 (0.64)
```

Simple illustration of Percent function:

```r
library(modelsummary)

dat <- mtcars
dat$cyl <- as.factor(dat$cyl)

fn <- function(x, y) {
    out <- sprintf(
        "%s (%.1f%%)",
        length(x),
        length(x) / length(y) * 100)
}
datasummary(
    cyl ~ Percent(fn = fn),
    data = dat)
```

| cyl | Percent |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | 11 (34.4%) |
| 6 | 7 (21.9%) |
| 8 | 14 (43.8%) |

Comment: Thank you for the hint, I am still trying to wrap my head around the new functions. Any idea on the issue of how to display the percentage in the same column as the count?

Comment: Yes, you can feed a custom function to the `Percent()` function. Here's an example with weighted percentages, but you can use the same logic to return whatever string you want: https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/articles/datasummary.html#weighted-percentages

Comment: I tried to apply it to my case and set up a function similar to the MeanSD one in my initial post: `NP = function(x, y) {
    N = N(x)
    P = Percent(fn = function(x, y) 100 * length(x) / length(y), denom = "col")
    out = paste(N, " (",P, ")", sep = "")
    return(out)
  }` and then call this function in datasummary. However, I get the following error :  This is a pseudo-function, not meant to be called.
 Sorry for all the questions.

Comment: I edited my answer with an example.

Comment: Outstanding support. Thank you so much!